# Get frame by frame data from mp4 using C# and .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mp4

I'm currently developing using Unity 3D, however my background is Apple development. In iOS/OSX development I can use `AVFoundation` to load an mp4 and get frame by frame data from it as it plays in BGRA format.

I was wondering what the equivalent of this is for .NET (Unity uses .NET 2.0)?

I know it's possible to call functions in an Objective-C++ file from unity but I need a way to do this on any platform not just iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no builtin way to access the video frame data **on mobile** in Unity. Playing videos in Unity on mobile devices is just sad. All they offer out of the box is [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html) that basically only works for full screen videos, like cut scenes.

If you want to do more complex things, like pipe a videos to a texture, you have two options:

- [Mobile Movie Texture](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2449)
- [Easy Movie Texture](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032)

*Note: there are more available on the asset store, but these are the two we use.*

*The best option?..*

**Easy Movie Texture**

We use Easy Movie Texture for our VR apps (Gear VR & Cardboard). There we decode up to 4k videos on an S6.

For stereo videos we use a component that comes with the plugin, VideoCopyTexture, that copies the texture data from the video into a material (to avoid duplicate decoding & rendering). It references **MediaPlayerCtrl.GetVideoTexture() that returns a Unity [Texture2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html), so from there you should have access to all the data you need!**

*The not so great option, but we kind of use it so I thought I would mention it anyway...*

**Mobile Movie Texture**

Mobile Movie Texture only works with ogg encoded videos. **I don't think it gives you access to the raw frame data, I would invite you to contact the dev directly or check the docs.**

But that can be "hacked". You can use a render texture, a separate camera that looks at a plane/quad with the video playing on it. Then grab that texture's bitmap data. It's not ideal, but should do the trick.

Long story short, I use a similar render to texture mechanism to pipe the video data to Scaleform, in Unity, and didn't see any performance loss. Mobile Movie Texture is not the fastest to start with and in our case even decodes in software on some devices. But it works everywhere. So we only use it for small videos.

Cheers,

J.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. It's pretty bad that Unity doesn't provide support for mobile video texture seeing as most modern phones are perfectly capable of it. I've come across Easy Movie Texture before and as I understand it it uses an Objective-C++ bridge to decode mp4 on iOS and a java one for android. Have you come across any .NET libraries that can be used with Unity like FFMPEG?

Comment: I've seen post by people using ffmpeg in Unity, but unsure if it was on mobile. I would check the unity answers site for anything ffmpeg.